# Updated property not recognized by $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive (Let's call it B) used inside another directive template (Let's call it A) as follows:

`<cr-carousel items="carouselData"></cr-carousel>`

The `carouselData` property is an array of objects.

Inside my controller for directive A I have a hook into an event in which I modify `carouselData` through `Array.prototype.splice.apply`:

`$scope.$on('carousel.keypress', function (event, data)  {
 ... some logic and branching
 Array.prototype.splice.apply($scope.carouselData, [someIndex, 0].concat(newItems));`

As you can see, I'm inserting new carousel items into the carousel at some index.

The carousel itself contains a repeater directive:

`<li ng-repeat="item in carouselData">`

which seems to be working just fine. Inserting new items into the carousel causes new items to appear in the list on the HTML end of things.

**The problem I'm having is that the `$watch` within directive B that's watching `carouselData` doesn't trigger when the new items are inserted.**

`$scope.$watch($attrs.items, function(value) {
    console.log("The elements for the carousel just changed.", value);
});`

I see the message show a couple of times when the page loads, but I get nothing when the new items are inserted. I've tried wrapping the `splice` code in a `$timeout` and also tried calling `$scope.$apply()` to see if that would trigger anything, and nadda.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

**Here's a JSFiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/urdjrqvL/**

Notice that `Here happened` is only logged to the console the first time the values are updated. When the value of the property is update in the `$timeout`, the items show in the HTML but the `$watch` doesn't fire.

Comment: This seems like it's a problem with your scope, see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes , if you can create a plunker or a fiddle then we can see what exactly is going on

Comment: Hi JoseM, I've updated my question with a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `$scope.$watch`, use `$scope.$watchCollection` in case of watching array changes. If you use `$watch`, there is a third parameter which specifies whether to watch for changes in value or reference. `Array.splice` only changes the array contents, not reference, so simple watch won't fire.

For details on $watch and $watchCollection, refer the correpsonding sections in this page-
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Thanks arghya. Can't believe I missed that one.